# Push in Angular Signals Array

Tags: angular, angular-signals

### Context:

With Angular 16, we can now use Signals.

But it doesn't seem clear to me how to do a simple **push** into an array.

The documentation suggests from [Angular Signal official doc](https://angular.io/guide/signals):

> When working with signals that contain objects, it's sometimes useful to mutate that object directly. For example, if the object is an array, you may want to push a new value without replacing the array entirely. To make an internal change like this, use the .mutate method

So it would be for example:

```
messages = signal<Message[]>([]);

ngOnInit(): void {
   const newMessage = ...
   this.messages.mutate(values => values.push(newMessage));
}
```

But it seems pretty weird to refer 2 times to the list. The first time with `this.messages` and the second one with `values`.

### Question:

How can I push an item into a Signal array?

Comment: You are creating a signal and not an array with messages = signal<Message[]>([]); and in the next line you are using mutate to mutate the signal by modifying the existing value i.e. values.push(newMessage). If you want yo see the value of your signal then you can use this.messages(). Another way is to use update this.messages.update(()=> [...this.messages(), newMessage]);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using `update` (instead of mutate that has been remove in v17).
Signal expect to be immutable (if you don't provide a compareFn when creating them).

```
messages = signal<Message[]>([]);

ngOnInit(): void {
   const newMessage = ...
   this.messages.update(values => {
      return [...values, newMessage];
   });
}
```

To sum up the types we are working with here:

- message: `Signal<Message[]>`
- values: `Message[]`

When you call `update()` you're invoking the method on a `Signal`. The signal here is the reactive primitive not the value itself.

You call that value with : `messages()`. This is signals 101.

Cf the definition of signals by Angular:

```
const SIGNAL = Symbol('SIGNAL');

export type Signal<T> = (() => T)&{
  [SIGNAL]: unknown;
};
```

So when you call update, you're actually telling the Signal to update its value.
`Signal.set()` just accepts a value to set so you're changing the reference, while `Signal.update()` takes a callback to update and you should be returning a new reference.

Comment: With angular 17, they have removed `mutate`. Maybe, you should update your answer.

Answer (score 5):

To expand upon what Matthieu noted, the magically awesome `mutate()` method was removed from the public API in the Angular 17 release. See [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/9ea54d47f50e2c6028fe9a70ff734fd455f75660) for more information about why it was removed.

It is important to note that both `set()` and `update()` rely upon reference equality for change detection, so calling array.push() will not change the value. You can try the following for

The following component will demonstrate how signals behave with array (and presumably objects as well):

```
import {
  Component,
  signal,
  computed,
  WritableSignal,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    Array Value: {{ computedDisplay() }}

    <div>
      <button
        (click)="appendValue()">
        Append value
      </button>
      <button
        (click)="appendAndShow()">
        Append and show
      </button>
      <button
        (click)="showWithUpdate()">
        Show only (using update())
      </button>
    </div>
  `,
  standalone: true,
})
export class AppComponent {
    private count = 1;
    private arraySignal: WritableSignal<string[]> = signal([]);

    public computedDisplay = computed(() => {
      return this.arraySignal().join(', ');
    });
  
  public appendValue() {
    this.arraySignal.update((arr: string[]) => {
      arr.push(`Update ${this.count++}`);
      return arr;
    });
  }

  public appendAndShow() {
    this.arraySignal.update((arr: string[]) => {
      arr.push(`Update ${this.count++}`);
      return arr.slice(0);
    });
  }

  public showWithSet() {
    this.arraySignal.set(this.arraySignal().slice(0));
  }

  public showWithUpdate() {
    this.arraySignal.update((arr: string[]) => {
      return arr.slice(0);
    });
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the suggestion in the [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/9ea54d47f50e2c6028fe9a70ff734fd455f75660) that removed `mutate`,

`this.messages.mutate(values => values.push(newMessage))` should change to `update`.

So Matthieu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196175/3613702) will change to,

```
messages = signal<Message[]>([]);

ngOnInit(): void {
   const newMessage = ...
   this.messages.update(values => [...values, newMessage]);
}
```

Reason, This change will force reference update (unlike `values.push()` which will still return the original array.